# 3G/4G not working in Samsung galaxy S3 SGH-I747M

Tags: 3g, 4g

My 3G and 4G is not working on SAMSUNG SGH-I747M. It's an AT&T version of S3 so according to specifications it must support both. Can anyone tell what should I modify in order to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your settings are correct.

Go to Settings → More networks → Mobile network → Network mode and select as the image below is selected. If this doesn't work it may be the signal strength in your area

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Well i can select this but to no effect. Signal strength is okay, other devices are working fine in the same area.